# HTML doesn't recognize diacritics

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, utf-8, utf

I'm trying to send the position of one of my ngFor objects as a parameter to one of my functions, but it returns the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: Parser Error: Missing expected ) at column 24 in [openProdus(produs.Poziție)]
```

This is the HTML where the error occurs:

```
        <img src= {{produs.Imagini}} (click)="openProdus(produs.Poziție)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing quotes around {{produs.Imagini}}. Fix that, and the other problem will probably take care of itself.

```
<img src="{{produs.Imagini}}" (click)="openProdus(produs.Poziție)" />
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me, I still get the same error.